# Дано действительное число а(1<а<3) .Составить алгоритм, находящий среди чисел 1 , 1+1/2 , 1+1/2+1/3 , ... первое, большее а

Tags: c, математика, ряды

Язык C.
Не могу найти ошибку.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<locale.h>
void main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
   float a, s=0;
   int i = 1;
   printf("Введите число больше 1 и меньше 3\n");
   scanf_s("%f", &a);
   if (a > 3 && a < 1) {
       printf("Ошибка!");
   }
   else {
       while (s <= a)
       {

           s = s + (1 / i);
           i++;
       }
       printf("%f\n", s);
   }
   
}
```

Comment: Для переносимости у `main` должен быть возвращаемый тип `int`

Comment: Сделала, но все равно бесконечный цикл. Ошибка не в этом.

Comment: В этом в том числе. Некоторые ошибки меняют наблюдаемое поведение, а некоторые не меняют

Comment: А условие `(a > 3 && a < 1)` тут только меня одного смущает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша самая большая ошибка - целочисленное деление

```
1 / i
```

каковое дает при `i>1` результат 0. Запишите деление как

```
s += 1.0/i
```

Только вот все равно ваша программа будет при реально больших числах работать неимоверно долго. Например, для 12 нужно 100000 итераций :( Да и точности `float` может не хватить.

Так что я бы изменил сам алгоритм - для чисел до 5-10 еще считал бы ряд, а для больших - использовал бы [асимптотическое приближение гармонического числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Впрочем, для `a < 3` достаточно 11 итераций, так что я, пожалуй, несколько забежал вперед :)

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: Написать не `1/i`, а `1.0/i`